# Give Infinitely Many Examples of Transitive Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that the set of natural numbers $\omega$ is a transitive set. So, how can we give infinitely many examples of transitive sets?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Check that $n$ is transitive for each $n < \omega$.

Comment: If $n$$\in$ $\omega$ then $n$ is a transitive set since $n$={$0,1,2,…,n−1$}.

Comment: @hayyam That's the right gist. Unfortunately, I cannot really tell whether this one line should count as a valid proof, because it depends on your knowledge (and definitions).